# SQL query is making multiple records

Tags: php, mysqli

```
<?php

    $msg = $_POST['postmsg'];

    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","somerset","chatroom") or die("sqlffs");

    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO `chat`(`msg`) VALUES ('$msg')");
    mysqli_close();

?>
```

My code is making multiple records in my DB.
I can not figure out why this is happening.

this is the code what runs the php

```
       function sendmsg(){
 $(document).keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {

                var message = $('#msgstring').val();
                //$('#show').html(message);
                if(message !="")
                {
                    $.post('sendmessage.php',{postmsg:message},
                    function(data){
                     exit();

                    });
                }

            }});
    }
```

Comment: Do you run the script multiple times?

Comment: Not with what you posted it won't. Get that cat off the mouse too. Why don't you show us your full and actual code?

Comment: I dont think I do. well I haven't coded it that way. I'll add more details.

Comment: @KyleSomerset: What debugging have you done for this?  Have you confirmed that only a single POST request is being sent to the server?  And that this one request is resulting in multiple records being added?  Also, why do you bind the `keypress` event inside of a function?  Where do you call that function?

Comment: I call it in in a form.
 <input onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;" type="text" onkeyup="sendmsg()" id="msgstring"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment:

> I call it in in a form. `<input onkeypress="return event.keyCode != 13;" type="text" onkeyup="sendmsg()" id="msgstring"/>`

What's happening is you're calling this function more than once:

```
sendmsg()
```

And what does this function do?  It binds a `keypress` event:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    // handle the event
});
```

That is, it doesn't *handle* the event.  It *binds the code* which handles the event.  So every time you call `sendmsg()` you create a duplicate binding.  Consider this sequence of events:

1. Call `sendmsg()`, the `keypress` event is bound.
2. Press the key, a POST request is made to create a record.
3. Call `sendmsg()` again, a *second* `keypress` event is bound.
4. Press a key again, *both* event handlers are executed and, thus, *two* POST requests are made and *two* records are created.
5. and so on...

Every time you press a key in your `input`, you trigger the event but you *also* create a duplicate event handler.  So each key press will result in more and more event handlers, and more and more records being created.

Only bind the event handler once:

```
// not inside a function
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    // handle the event
});
```

Then any time you press a key in your `input` you would automatically be invoking this event handler.  So you don't need the code repeated in the `input`:

```
<input type="text" id="msgstring"/>
```

Comment: I only want it to make the request when the enter button is pressed.

Comment: @KyleSomerset: Isn't that what this ensures?:  `if(e.which == 13)`  First fix this problem, *then* address whether or not that is working.  Right now you're re-binding the event with *every* key press, which you don't want to do.

Comment: thanks that actually made scene when I read it a second time cheers.